# Como acesar uma array dentro de um objeto?

Tags: php

Como acessar um array dentro de um objeto?

```
$user = $pdo->query("SELECT * from users LIMIT 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'id' => '104',
   'name' => 'John',
   'sex' => 'male',
   'car' => 'Toyota',
))
```

Comment: Recomendo você utilizar `->fetchObject()`. Mais simples.

Comment: Tentou sumplesmente `$arraydeobjetos[$indice]->propriedade` ? ex: `$user[0]->name;`

Answer (score 1):

Para [acessar um array dentro de um objeto](http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php), basta passar o index através de chaves.

```
$user->{'0'}->id
$user->{'0'}->name
$user->{'0'}->sex
$user->{'0'}->car
```

Comment: Isso aí são `chaves` e não `colchetes` :D

Comment: @dvd grato pela correção. Acabou passando batido.